# Apply a new template to an already-existing PowerPoint presentation on a Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I want to apply a new template (created by my organization) to an already-existing PowerPoint presentation.  Anyone know how to do this?  I am working on a Mac.  Apparently, the instructions I have found are for Windows machines and don't apply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open your existing presentation.
2. Go to the Design tab, and the theme ribbon (the ribbon on the left).
3. Hover over the ribbon and watch for the down arrow to appear.
4. Click the down arrow.
5. Click "Browse for themes…"
6. Navigate to your template file.
7. Select the file.

That should do it.